# Merge duplicated emails and points mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which has three columns:

```
Userid         | Email               | Points
---------------------------------------------------------
1              | jdoe@company.com    | 20
2              | jdoe%40company.com  | 25
3              | rwhite@company.com  | 14
4              | rwhite%40company.com| 10
```

What I want to do is to delete duplicate email and merge points. I want my table to look like this:

```
Userid         | Email               | Points
---------------------------------------------------------
1              | jdoe@company.com    | 45
3              | rwhite@company.com  | 24
```

How would my query look like to return my desire table?

Anyone knows how to do this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT MIN(userid) userid, email, SUM(points) points
  FROM 
(
  SELECT userid, REPLACE(email, '%40', '@') email, points
    FROM table1
) q
  GROUP BY email
```

Output:

```
| USERID |              EMAIL | POINTS |
|--------|--------------------|--------|
|      1 |   jdoe@company.com |     45 |
|      3 | rwhite@company.com |     24 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3caab/5)** demo

---

Now if you want to deduplicate your table in-place you can do

```
-- Fix emails
UPDATE table1
   SET email = REPLACE(email, '%40', '@')
 WHERE email LIKE '%\%40%';
-- Merge points for duplicate records
UPDATE table1 t JOIN
(
  SELECT email, SUM(points) points
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY email
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) q ON t.email = q.email
   SET t.points = q.points;
-- Delete all duplicate records except ones with lowest `userid`
DELETE t 
  FROM table1 t JOIN
(
  SELECT MIN(userid) userid, email
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY email
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) q ON t.email = q.email
 WHERE t.userid <> q.userid;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fce83f/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Use this query assuming you want to match email as is without any modification

```
SELECT MIN(user_id), SUM(points)as points, email FROM table_name GROUP BY email
```